# How to get subtext in ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, listview

Which property sets the subtext as highlighted [here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vljfb9&s=6) in a ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a custom xml file as layout for your adapter setting. See this tutorial [how to create custom views for listview](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

Comment: To elaborate, there is no 'property' for this. Your adapter's `getView` method can return any sort of view you like to serve as a list item. There's no requirement that you inflate list item views from XML, but it certainly can make things easier and cleaner. :) Be sure you reuse the view provided in the `convertView` parameter to `getView` when present or you'll forfeit much of the optimization that ListView provides.